# Getting Google API verification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I just finished programming my app and I got a little problem. In summary, my app use the data that I give it and insert events in Google Calendar. The problem is that after finishing it and putting it In Production, I keep getting the warning about the app being not verified. The problem is that I don't have any domain for verification. The app will be hosted on a public github repository. After trying to solve it, I now get this message:

> *Needs verification
>  Because you're using one or more sensitive scopes, your app registration requires verification by Google. Please prepare your app to submit for verification. Learn more *

Does that means that my app could be unusable if I don't comply with the verification and is it possible to verify the app with a public Github repo?

I tried using the link of my github repo for verification but didn't worked because I needed to verify that I own the github domain

Answer (score 0):

This is Google verification that you need to go through.    When you have any app that has a consent screen and requests consent to access private user data of people other than yourself you need to apply for verification.

Go to Google cloud console under the consent screen and review what is needed for verification.    Its an extensive process.

Comment: But can I do it with only a github repo or I need to buy a domain and create a website for my app?

Comment: Verification will require you have a domain to host your privacy policies and other things

Comment: Can I host my privacy policies on github instead of buying a domain?

Comment: No it needs to be your own verified domp